# Why does the battery on every laptop I use permanently die and need replacing?

Tags: windows

In the past three years I have used a 2015 Mac Book Pro and two outdated PCs. Every time one of these has been put into my possession, the battery gives up within a few months. The second laptop I am referring to was a laptop assigned to me at work, I only used it 3-5 times, yet within a few months it would no longer function unless plugged in. This is the case in all three instances, I have never had a problem with water damage or dropping any of the computers. There has been no harm done to these computers, the only thing they have in common is that I am the user and I typically have my email logged in on all three. What is the reason this is happening?

Comment: Help me understand how this is a security question, as defined in the help center.

Comment: Did you use these laptops very infrequently? If that's the case, then you probably have let the battery drain to zero for an extended amount of time (note there's a small drain even when the laptop is turned off). Lithium batteries doesn't like being completely drained for extended amount of times. Best practice is to keep it around 70% charge, and to occasionally check the battery to maintain that level of charge. Also this is not a security question.

Comment: Exactly as @LieRyan says, LiPo batteries tend to have short lives when mistreated, and what such batteries consider mistreating may not be intuitive. I have 5 computers that are just like that myself (though they lasted maybe 6 months). They hold a charge for about 10 minutes. Welcome to the world of computers.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the original users abused the batteries -  and the batts were basically dead when you were given them.

You expected “normal use” and after a time the batts couldn’t keep up.

If you have a machine from new then you will see the difference...

Answer (score 0):

You could have been unluckly. The obvious but unsatafactory answer. If that is why then whatever you have done or will do will not really affect the life of the next battery.

That being said, lithium batteries do not like:

1. Being kept hot (sitting on a desk in direct sunlight)
2. Being frozen
3. Being drained down to their last drop before being recharged*
4. Being constantly kept fully charged

Are you doing any thing like that?

*This is something that you were meant to do with NiCd rechargeable batteries (the memory effect) However is something you should NOT do with Lithium batteries.